# Unable to iterate result of splitting string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, split

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
System.log( "inputExecArgs = " + inputExecArgs );
System.log( "Object.prototype.toString.call( inputExecArgs ) = " + Object.prototype.toString.call( inputExecArgs ) );

var inputTokens = inputExecArgs.split( "{" );
System.log( "inputTokens = " + inputTokens );

if ( inputTokens = null ){
    System.log( "inputTokens is null" );
}else{
    System.log( "inputTokens not null" );

    System.log( "Object.prototype.toString.call( inputTokens ) = " +     Object.prototype.toString.call( inputTokens ) );
Object.prototype.toString.call( inputTokens ) );

    System.log( "----- begin iterating through inputTokens -----" );
    for (var key in inputTokens) {
        //if (tokens.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            System.log( key + " -> " + inputTokens[key] );
        //}
    }
    System.log( "----- end iterating through inputTokens -----" );

    var tokensLength = tokens.length
    System.log( "tokensLength = " + tokensLength );

}
```

The iteration seems to not work and "inputTokens.length" results in an error:

```
inputExecArgs =  } {token1} {token2} {
Object.prototype.toString.call( inputExecArgs ) = [object String]
inputTokens =  } ,token1} ,token2} ,
inputTokens not null
Object.prototype.toString.call( inputTokens ) = [object Main]
----- begin iterating through inputTokens -----
----- end iterating through inputTokens -----
Error in (Workflow:Andrew.Parse_input_properties / parse string for curly bracket properties (item1)#37) ReferenceError: "tokens" is not defined.
Workflow execution stack:
***
item: 'Andrew.Parse_input_properties/item1', state: 'failed', business state: 'null', exception: 'ReferenceError: "tokens" is not defined. (Workflow:Andrew.Parse_input_properties / parse string for curly bracket properties (item1)#37)'
workflow: 'Andrew.Parse_input_properties' (d5f4738e-e947-45d2-a123-cc62696c1a31) 
|  'input': name=inputExecArgs type=string value= } {token1} {token2} {
|  'output': name=outputExecArgs type=string value=null
|  'no attributes'
*** End of execution stack.
```

I don't know if this matters but this is VMware vRO 7 which uses Rhino 1.7R4.

Comment: `if ( inputTokens = null )` That is assigning null to inputTokens, not comparing inputTokens to null.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change this line:

```
if (inputTokens = null) {
```

to, for example:

```
if (inputTokens.length > 0) {
```

What you have right now literally assigns the value `null` to `inputTokens`, THEN results in a falsey value, so the `else` branch is taken.

As an aside, to compare with `null`, you could use the `===` operator. `.split` on a `String` will never result in `null`. If there are no tokens to split on (e.g. when the string is empty `""`), the result is simply an empty array `[]`.

Comment: Yes, that fixed my problem. The difference in syntax between PowerShell and JavaScript was what tripped me up.

Testing against null was a debugging step which I see now wasn't that helpful anyway.

Thanks.